# Вычисление интеграла методом Симпсона

Tags: c++, c, алгоритм, математика

Как написать функцию для вычисления определенного интеграла методом Симпсона ?

Comment: Вы формулу Симпсона знаете?

Comment: Нет, поясните.

Comment: http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A4%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BC%D1%83%D0%BB%D0%B0_%D0%A1%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%BF%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B0

Comment: Код:

    double integrating3(double a, double b, int n, double (*f)(double x) ) {
 double sum = 0.0;
 sum = ( (b-a)/6 ) * ( f(a) + 4 * f( (a+b)/2 ) + f(b) );
 return sum;
    }

Comment: Уже лучше, только осталось лишнее выкинуть

Comment: Я написал-то, но если сравнить с методом треугольника, то результат ОЧЕНЬ отличается.

Comment: Так метод же очень приблизительный...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
double SimpsonMethod(double a, double b, unsigned n, double (*f)(double x)) {

    double h = (b - a) / n;
    double sum = 0;

    double x0 = a;
    double x1 = a + h;

    for (unsigned i=0; i<=n-1; i++) {
        sum += f(x0) + 4*f(x0 + h/2) + f(x1);

        x0 += h;
        x1 += h;
    }

    return (h/6)*sum;
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Существует известная [формула](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A4%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BC%D1%83%D0%BB%D0%B0_%D0%A1%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%BF%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B0) для вычисления значения интеграла на некотором отрезка `[a, b]`. Ваша задача - разбить исходный отрезок `[A, B]` на некоторое количество подотрезков `[a_n, b_n`] и на каждом из них сосчитать значение интеграла с помощью формулы Симпсона. Далее необходимо сложить все полученные значения.

В зависимости от выбранного разбиения будет меняться точность конечного ответа. Здесь, кстати говоря, возникает более интересная задача *о выборе необходимых отрезков для максимизации точности при минимизации числа вычислений,* которая, правда, требует некоторых знаний численных методов и теории по работе с погрешностями.

---

*Ваша функция на языке `C++` может выглядеть примерно следующим образом:*

```
typedef float float_t;
typedef ... function_t;

float_t PartIntegrateWithSimpsonMethod(function_t f, float_t a, float_t b)
{
    // Реализация метода симпсона для отрезка [a, b]
}

float_t IntegrateWithSimpsonMethod(function_t f, float_t a, float_t b)
{
    if (b < a) throw ...;

    // Вариант с равномерным делением на отрезки.
    const std::size_t steps = 20;
    assert(steps > 1);

    const float_t singleStep = (b - a) / steps;
    float_t result = 0;
    for (std::size_t i = 0; i < (steps - 1); ++i)
    {
        const float_t localA = i * singleStep;
        const float_t localB = (i + 1) * singleStep;    
        result += PartIntegrateWithSimpsonMethod(f, localA, localB);
    }

    return result;
}
```

**Ваша задача теперь - реализовать сам метод Симпсона и понять, как правильно передавать исходную функцию через некоторый `function_t`, и то, и то - дело техники.**

---

Кстати говоря, *"на подумать"* - определите, в чем недостатки предложенного кода и что можно было бы сделать лучше.

Comment: @qwerty12359 Браво.

Comment: Будьте перфекционистом, реализуйте еще последовательное увеличение числа отрезков с достижением заданной точности.

Comment: И так нормально. Зачем себе заморачивать кое-что? =)

Answer (score 3):

В ответе @nullptr идет постоянное перевычисление одних и тех же данных, только поэтому и предлагаю свой вариант (писал очень давно, интеграл с заданной погрешностью...)

```
double Simpson(double a, double b, double eps, double (*f)(double))
{
    double N = 4.;
    double sum1 = 0., sum2 = 0.;
    double x, h;
    double index1, index2;
    unsigned int i;
    double func;
    for(;;) {  // В принципе на случай расходимостей лучше поставить ограничитель по числу итераций...
        h = (b-a)/N;
        sum1 = sum2 = -(f(a)+f(b));
        index1 = index2 = 4.;
        i = 0;
        for(x = a; x <= b+h/2.; x+=h) {
            sum1 +=  (index1 = 6.-index1)*(func=f(x));
            if (i++%2==0) {
                sum2 += (index2 = 6.-index2)*func;
            };
        };
        if (fabs((sum1-2.*sum2)/sum1)<=eps) return (h*sum1)/3.+h*(2.*sum2-sum1)/45.; else N*=2.;
    };
    return (h*sum1)/3.;
};
```