# Интегрирование методом Симпсона

Tags: c++, математика

Здравствуйте. Мне нужно было написать программу, которая вычисляет интеграл методом трапеций и Симпсона. С методом трапеций всё нормально(в Excel проверял), а вот с Симпсоном есть проблемы. Результат должен быть такой же, как с трапецией или немного отличаться от него. 
Результаты:

Трапеций - 0.909313
Симпсона - 0.701743

Отличие есть существенное. В чём я мог сделать ошибку?

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <conio.h>
#include <math.h>
using namespace std;

const double a = 0.8;
const double b = 2.4;
const int steps = 10;

double Function(double x)
{
    return sqrt(1.5*x + 2.3) / (3.0 + sqrt(0.3*x + 1.0));
}

double TrapezeIntegrate(double step, int steps, double y[])
{
    double sum = 0.0;
    for (int i = 1; i <= steps; i++)
        sum += y[i];
    return step*((y[0] + y[steps - 1]) / 2 + sum);
}

double SimpsonsIntegrate(double step, int steps, double y[])
{
    double sumEven = 0.0, sumOdd = 0.0;
    for (int i = 1; i < steps; i += 2)
        if (!(i == steps - 1))
            sumOdd += y[i];
        else
            break;
    for (int i = 2; i < steps - 1; i += 2)
        sumEven += y[i];
    return step/3*(y[0]+2*sumEven+4*sumOdd+y[steps]);
}

int main()
{
    double *y = new double[steps+1];
    double *segments = new double[steps+1];
    double step = (b - a) / steps;
    double tmp = a;
    cout << "Trapeze solution"  << endl;
    cout << "Step: "<< step     << endl;
    for (int i = 0; i <= steps; i++)
    {
        segments[i] = tmp;
        tmp += step;
    }
    for (int i = 0; i <= steps; i++)
        y[i] = Function(segments[i]);
    cout << "S\tY" << endl;
    for (int i = 0; i < steps + 1; i++)
    {
        cout << segments[i] << "\t" << y[i] << endl;
    }
    cout << "___" << endl;
    cout << "Result [Trapeze]: " << TrapezeIntegrate(step, steps, y) << endl;
    cout << "Result [Simpson]: " << SimpsonsIntegrate(step, steps, y);
    _getch();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: зачем sumOdd и sumEven ? Почему просто не использовать формулу  `(b-a)/6*(y[0]+4*Function((a+b)/2)+y[steps]);` ?

Comment: Ну как зачем? В формуле написано, что есть сумма четных и нечетных y

Comment: с какой целью? Если на том месте должно быть лишь значение функции в середине отрезка a,b

Comment: @ Ni55aN Фрмула Симпсона получается при сложении steps/2 таких выражений (через одну точку).

Comment: Похожий вопрос: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/49053/Вычисление-интеграла-методом-Симпсона/49074#49074

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Формула Симпсона получается суммированием выражений вида
 `(b-a)/6*(y[0]+4*Function((a+b)/2)+y[steps]);` ([Ni55aN](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/20555/ni55an))
через одну точку.
Из рисунка следует, что для формулы Симпсона `steps` надо брать нечётным.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

Вообще-то говоря, вы сам интеграл считали? Может, это просто погрешность счета? :) Потому как точное значение - 0.82.

Заменим steps на 100 - и результаты сразу окажутся почти одинаковыми :)